# Javascript with JQuery working locally but not on Heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I'm working on a Rails application where we are using simple Javascript with JQuery.  The JS is working locally, but not at all when deployed to Heroku.  We seem to be getting these errors:

[image: errors]

Could these errors contribute to the JavaScript not working on Heroku?  The fonts are being imported with the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

The font awesome icons are showing up, suggesting that the font is being imported correctly, and yet the errors seem to say otherwise. Any ideas?

Comment: the url reference and version that you're using for font-awesome is different than the url in the errors.

Comment: Might that suggest that the error is coming from elsewhere?

Comment: yes you're right. try removing the reference for font-awesome and check if it still works

Comment: I removed the link to the stylesheet, but that removed all the font-awesome icons

Comment: hmm. so its referencing your link for the font-awesome icons. are you by any chance referring to the url in the error anywhere in your code? can you do a quick search and check?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec!

Comment: ok. I am guessing that one of your config settings is referring to this url

Comment: So the url is being used in the CSS for @font-face, `src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');`

Comment: thats the issue. its trying to find the font in your fonts folder and throwing this error.

Comment: can you try the steps mentioned in this article http://blog.fieldforceapp.com/post/43193973420/moving-to-heroku-bootstrap-font-awesome-html?

Comment: Okay, working on it!

Comment: great. let me know if it worked.

Comment: did it work for you @tibsar?

Comment: Okay, so I got the javascript to work.  There were duplicate files which was causing issues.  However, after following the tutorial I got the font errors to go away on localhost but not on Heroku

Comment: oh, so you don't have any more references pointing to the old version now?

Comment: what url are the errors pointing to now?

Comment: were you able to fix the issue?